# Как проверить угрожает ли слон фигуре с заданными координатами?

Tags: c++, математика, шахматы

Имеется такая задача:

> На шахматном поле в (k, l) расположен слон. Угрожает ли он фигуре стоящей на  (m, n)? Предусмотреть обработку ошибочного ввода пользователя (выдавать диагностическое сообщение).

И моя попытка решить ее:

```
int k, l, m, n;
cout << "Введите расположение слона k: ";
cin >> k;
cout << endl;
cout << "Введите расположение слона l: ";
cin >> l;
cout << endl;
cout << "Введите расположение другой фигуры m: ";
cin >> m;
cout << endl;
cout << "Введите расположение другой фигуры n: ";
cin >> n;
cout << endl;
if (m < 1 || m > 8 || k < 1 || k > 8 || l < 1 || l > 8 || n < 1 || n > 8) {
    cout << "Введены недопустимые значение!";
    return 0;
}

if (k == l && m == n) {
    cout << "Две фигуры не могут стоять на одном месте!";
}

while (k <= 8 || l <= 8) {
    k++;
    l++;
    if (k == m && l == n) {
        cout << "Угрожает";
        return 0;
    }
}

while (k <= 8 || l <= 8) {
    k--;
    l--;
    if (k == m && l == n) {
        cout << "Угрожает";
        return 0;
    }
}

while (k <= 8 || l <= 8) {
    k++;
    l--;
    if (k == m && l == n) {
        cout << "Угрожает";
        return 0;
    }
}

while (k <= 8 || l <= 8) {
    k--;
    l++;
    if (k == m && l == n) {
        cout << "Угрожает";
        return 0;
    }
}

cout << "Не угрожает";
```

По моей логике слон может двигаться в 4-ех направлениях, для этого и служат 4 цикла while, которые и меняют значение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Или я таки не смыслю в шахматах, или слон (в просторечьи - офицер :)) ходит по диагонали... Так что так, как **нарисовано** - странно :)

Comment: @Harry, так он и ходит по диагонали, на рисунке показано, что делает цикл while, он меняет значения на один вправо и на один вверх например, и получается перескакивает на следующую клетку по диагонали

Comment: @Harry, ничего вы не смыслите, это конный офицер (сарказм).

Comment: Ну, цикл тут точно не нужен...

Comment: Особенно такой цикл - `while (k <= 8 || l <= 8) {
    k--;
    l--;` - вы не прикидывали, когда он кончится, если фигура не под боем? :)

Comment: а если выполняется первое условие, то  другое может и не выполниться...

Answer (score 7):

Вроде как условие угрозы -

```
((x_слона-x) == (y_слона-y))||((x-x_слона) == (y_слона-y))
```

или просто

```
abs(x_слона-x) == abs(y_слона-y)
```

Понятно, что ставить на клетку со слоном фигуру нельзя :), так что добавьте в проверку

```
... || (k==m && l==n) ...
```

Дальше - просто

```
cout << (abs(k-m)!=abs(l-n) ? "Не угрожает" : "Угрожает";
```

Comment: точно,   лучше проще...